# How do I return an image after it has been called?

Tags: java, android, image, animation

Here's my code so far. So when I click the image, it moves as expected. Cool. But when I click the image again, it does not move back to the original location. Can someone help? FYI, variable "depends" is at a global scope. Thanks!

```
depends = false;

image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (depends){
            TranslateAnimation noob =
                new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, +90);

            noob.setDuration(1000);
            noob.setFillAfter(true);
            image.startAnimation(noob);
        } else{
            TranslateAnimation translateAnimation =
                new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, -90);
            depends = true;
            translateAnimation.setDuration(1000);
            translateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
            image.startAnimation(translateAnimation);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the old Animation API will only translate the Drawable of the View, but not the View itself (and its touch area). If you click where the original image "was" you should see it move back

**Solution**: use the new `Animator` API [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) and [nineoldandrois](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) for back compatibility

Comment: I updated my answer. Off top of my head and without more context, I would say something like the following should do: `ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(image, "translationY", 0.f, 90.f); anim.setDuration(1000); anim.start();`

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark.  If this doesn't help I'll delete my answer.

```
            if (depends){
                TranslateAnimation noob = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, +90);



                noob.setDuration(1000);

                noob.setFillAfter(true);

                image.startAnimation(noob);

                depends = false;  <-- ADD THIS
            } else{
                TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, -90);

                   depends = true;

                translateAnimation.setDuration(1000);

                translateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);

                image.startAnimation(translateAnimation);
            }
```

Comment: Nothing happened. Appreciate the attempt tho!

Comment: Am I at least correct in assuming that your "else" block is not being hit?

Comment: Yes you are. And it's actually my fault for not telling you that I initialized the depends boolean variable as false at the original scope. See the revision.